# exec 2010 VBA related error: "can't find project...."

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

Have made a (refinery process industry-)model under Excel 2010 with many macro's (based on a Excel 2003 sheet)
Had some difficulties getting it to run wih the right addins but OK now.

However, other people with Win7/64 bit have problems getting it to run with error:
"can't run project or library" which suggest not the right addins are loaded. Various fora now suggest to look at VBA tools/references for "missing" but the system is locked in a loop of errors and tools/references is no longer accessible.

How do I find out which addins are still missing? have tried to de-activate all addids on my own machine but cannot reproduce the error

Comment: Does your VBA project contain any references to Windows library files or drivers (e.g. `kernel32.dll` or `GDI32.dll`)? I've run into similar issues with GDI+ image conversion code created in 32-bit environment that would not compile in 64-bit environment.

Answer (score 0):

In the VB Editor, go to Tools menu > References, and look for any items in the list that are indicated with [MISSING].

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me running a VBA macro in 32-bit Excel on 64-bit Windows 10 v1803. My older version was Excel 97, but I don't think that is relevant.

- Navigate to `Excel.exe`, right-click and choose `Properties`
- On the `Compatibility` tab select `Run this program as an administrator`. You may wish to set the `Compatibility mode` as well (for example to `Windows XP (Service Pack 3)`).
- Open Excel, then open your spreadsheet containing the VBA macro
- Run the macro...problem solved!

If you need to open a spreadsheet regularly, follow these steps:

- Create a shortcut to your spreadsheet
- Right-click the shortcut and choose `Properties`
- Change `Target` from `[PATH]\MySheet.xls` to `"[PATH-TO-EXCEL]\EXCEL.EXE" "[PATH]\MySheet.xls"`

Now when you double-click the shortcut, Excel will load the spreadsheet and you can run your macro.